# Jquery best way to initiate toggle on page load

Tags: jquery

so I am have some divs set up with a toggle function, and I want the first to be toggled visible on page load, what is the best way to do this? Thanks

```
$('.paneltop').click( function(){
    $(this).next('div').animate(
    {'height':"toggle"});
    $(this).toggleClass('openpane')
```

Comment: Easier to answer if we have HTML, and more context of where you have this JS.

Comment: all i need is the height that is being toggled in the above function to be toggled open on page load

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `jQuery.toggle` along with `.ready()`. 
It should look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".paneltop").next("div").toggle();
});
```

Note: if you want it to be open, you can use `.show()` instead of `.toggle()`.

jQuery.toggle - http://api.jquery.com/toggle/